# RODBC NOT available for 2.15.2

Tags: rodbc

I am using R version of 2.15.2 and tried installing RODBC package. However, I got a warning message that "RODBC is not available for 2.15.2" and it's builded based on 2.15.3. I believed I used to use 2.15.2 and never got this problem. Any body got same problems and how did you solve it? I don't want to upgrade to higher version

Comment: Why upgrading is not an option?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  Download the `.tar.gz` file then call `install.packages` on the local file

---

Longer answer:

1. Ask google to point you to the archive for the source files for the package of interest. If the package is hosted on `CRAN`, you will likely find yourself [here: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RODBC/](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RODBC/)
2. Search through the `news` items to see which is the latest available package version for your version of `R`. (In this case, 1.3.7)
3. In R:

   ```
   # Where you will save the file, locally        
   localFile <- "~/RODBC.tar.gz"  #or wherever appropriate
   remoteFile <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RODBC/RODBC_1.3-7.tar.gz"

   # download the file
   download.file(remoteFile, localFile)

   # Install from local source
   install.packages(localFile, repos=NULL, type="source")

   # optionally delete the downloaded file
   unlink(localFile)
   ```